# Configure block equivalent for Jenkins 2.0 Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

For the Job DSL Plugin (https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin) you can script your Jenkins jobs using this plugins DSL script with the help of their built in methods to support most plugins.

When you encounter a plugin that is not yet supported you can still use it by using a "Configure" block (https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/The-Configure-Block) that tells the plugin how to build the XML manually.

Is there an equivalent feature for the new Jenkins 2.0 pipeline (https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/) to support plugins that are either not updated often or at least until the plugin author adds support?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [new Jenkinsfile capabilities](https://jenkins.io/blog/2016/09/06/jenkins-world-speaker-blog-pipeline-model-definition/). In essence, you can now configure your entire job using the Jenkinsfile and pipeline approach.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. My question is when there is something that the Jenkinsfile does not support yet, is there a way to add support without having to convince the plugin owner to update their plugin?